# How to align RowSupportFragment items to the center just like VerticalGridSupportFragment in leanback

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

Here, I am developing a home for the Android TV. And I have a list of String for Menu that I have populated on RowSupportFragment. Because Using VeriticalGridFragment is not feasible here. Now I have populated a list of String as Menu for the Android TV. But I cannot center the list like VerticalGridSupportFragment. I need to center the RowSupportFragment to match the designs. Here is the design provided to me.

I want to show RowSupportFragment like this at the center just like VerticalGridSupportFragment does to the list provided.

[image: I want to show RowSupportFragment like this as a Menu at the center just like VerticalGridSupportFragment does]

Please help me out with this. How can I center the list in RowSupportFragment.